# Facebook Dashboard API.... fail to use it :|

Tags: php, facebook

This question is about **Dashboard.addNews** and **Dashboard.publishActivity**

Facebook has told the public about its new Dashboard API, however it hasn't provided any updates on its library to use the new code.

So I followed the advice in this link
http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=197753
to add the new functions to the facebookapi_php5_restlib.php

```
//dashboard functions
  public function dashboard_addNews($uid, $news, $image = null) { 
    return $this->call_method('facebook.dashboard.addNews',
                              array('uid' => $uid,
                                    'news' => $news,
                                    'image' => $image));
  }

  public function dashboard_multiAddNews($uids, $news, $image = null) { 
    return $this->call_method('facebook.dashboard.multiAddNews',
                              array('uids' => $uids ? json_encode($uids) : null,
                                    'news' => $news,
                                    'image' => $image));
  }

  public function dashboard_addGlobalNews($news, $image = null) {
    return $this->call_method('facebook.dashboard.addGlobalNews',
                              array('news' => $news,
                                    'image' => $image));
  }

  public function dashboard_publishActivity($activity, $image = null) {
    return $this->call_method('facebook.dashboard.publishActivity',
                              array('activity' => $activity,
                                    'image' => $image));
  }

  public function dashboard_multiIncrementCount($uids) {
    return $this->call_method(
      'facebook.dashboard.multiIncrementCount', array('uids' => json_encode($uids)));
  }

  public function dashboard_removeActivity($activity_ids) {
    return $this->call_method(
      'facebook.dashboard.removeActivity', array('activity_ids' => json_encode($activity_ids)));
  }

  public function dashboard_setCount($uid, $count) {
    return $this->call_method('facebook.dashboard.setCount',
                              array('uid' => $uid,
                                    'count' => $count));
  }
```

But now when I follow the sample code at
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Dashboard.addNews

```
$image = 'http://www.martialdevelopment.com/wordpress/wp-content/images/cheezburger-or-dim-mak.jpg'; 
$news = array(array('message' => 'Your friend @:563683308 just sent you a present!', 'action_link' => array('text' => 'Get Your Gift', 'href' => 'http://www.example.com/gifts?id=5878237'))); 
$facebook->api_client->dashboard_addNews($user_id, $news, $image);
```

However it will prompt this error:

```
[Wed Jan 27 03:42:27 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /var/local/site/webroot/xxxx/facebookapi_php5_restlib.php on line 2009
```

the code at that php line is

```
if (is_array($val)) $val = implode(',', $val);
```

pls notice that I haven't altered the facebookapi_php5_restlib.php except pasting those suggested dashboard function code.

and when I follow the instruction at http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Dashboard.publishActivity and try to use it:

```
$image = 'http://www.martialdevelopment.com/wordpress/wp-content/images/cheezburger-or-dim-mak.jpg'; 
$activity = array(array('message' => '{*actor*} just sponsored @:563683308!', 'action_link' => array('text' => 'Sponsor this cause', 'href' => 'http://www.example.com/games?id=5878237'))); 
$facebook->api_client->dashboard_publishActivity($activity, $image);
```

it throws out the same error too about "Array to string conversion"

Any suggestion to actually use the new Facebook Dashboard API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found that no need to modify the php class at all.

All we need to do is use the call_method

```
$news = array(array('message' => 'There is a new level in the dungeon!', 'action_link' => array('text' => 'Play now.', 'href' => 'http://www.example.com/gifts?id=5878237'))); 
$facebook->api_client->call_method('facebook.dashboard.addGlobalNews', array('news' => $news));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't assign into the same variable, the warning will likely go away:

```
if (is_array($val)) $stringval = implode(',', $val);
```

Comment: hey it's the original code inside facebookapi_php5_restlib.php